# Less - search in multiple files at once

Tags: linux, unix, logging, less

Hi I would like to know if there is possibility to search trough multiple files at once using less. I am facing problem, that I should go trough multiple logs (instance1.log, instance2.log, instance3.log ...) and search for some test. Right now I am able to open multiple files in the less using `less instance?.log` but than I need to manually search trough the files and search each one individually, but I would like to search trough all of them at once. Is there such a option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the `less` man page under the `/pattern` command:

```
          Certain characters are special if entered at  the  beginning  of
          the  pattern;  they modify the type of search rather than become
          part of the pattern:
```

...

```
          ^E or *
                 Search multiple files.  That is, if  the  search  reaches
                 the  END of the current file without finding a match, the
                 search continues in the next file  in  the  command  line
                 list.
```

So for example, use less to open multiple files:

```
less file1 file2
```

Then type `/^E` or `/*` followed by your search pattern. Use `n` to navigate forward through pattern matches and `shift+n` to navigate backward through pattern matches (spanning multiple files).

Answer (score 0):

This is an off-topic question but you can use `grep`. Check out this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171314/how-to-grep-for-same-string-but-multiple-files-at-the-same-time)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you want, but you can do

```sh
cat instance?.log | less
```

And then search through the result.

Or use grep as it is the tool that is basically made for this use case:

```
grep -E 'search term' instance?.log
```